# Can't undo something in Node Editor

Tags: materials, node-editor, workflow

I accidentally deleted a Color Ramp node that I was working all my colors on, and now when I <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Undoing is done with `Ctrl`+`Z` menu. You can try access undo history `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Z` and proceed from there (at least you'll know whether or not undoing is possible).

Comment: Seems like undo is broken in the node editor completely. This should be reported as a bug.

Comment: I have the same issue. Yesterday Undo worked fine in node editor, but today it doesn't. The undo history shows all changes, but nothing happens when I select something. :(

Comment: I must admit that I am surprised to see the same behavior even in 2023 in the current Blender versions. I have to assume that this is indeed a bug in Blender.

Comment: Yes it is a known issue https://developer.blender.org/T71895

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that undo in the geometry node editor window only works when my 3D view window is in object mode, more specifically, **not** in edit mode.

Comment: I found this problem on Google, and this was exactly my problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The above solution should work, but it seems like a bug in the Undo history for the nodes editor.

**Solution**

1. Switch to the 3d view
2. Make a change, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (it should work)
3. Go back to the node editor, edit something, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works again. Heureka!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check User Preferences➜Editing➜ Undo➜ Step is not set to 0.
2. Try undo from dropdown menu(assume tho you have tried this alraedy)
3. Try restoring default key layout.

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. You probably switched to a QWERTZ keyboard configuration (for example DE) by accident, and are too far in the 3d zone to notice or think of it.